# what's wrong with this custom adapter?

Tags: android

My custom adapter is not working. I want to show a listview, every row of listview with a relative layout which has a text, an edittext and two buttons. I have initialize a String of names. element of String names will vary in every row of listview.
I'm new in android. Kindly point out error and also mention why output is not visible. 
here is code

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  ListView listView;
  String[] names=new String[]{
            "Name1" , "Name2" , "Name3"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this,names));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text))
                       .getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }

    });

    }



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


Context context;
final String[] Name;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] Name)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.Name=Name;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View listView;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        listView=new View(context);
        listView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);
        TextView name=(TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        name.setText(Name[position]);
        EditText editText=(EditText) listView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setHint("write here");
        Button btn1=(Button) listView.findViewById(R.id.btnok);
        name.setText("OK");
        Button btn2=(Button) listView.findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
        name.setText("cancel");
    }
    else
    {
        listView= (View) convertView;
    }

    return listView;
}





@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Name.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


  }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/childlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.customlayout.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnok"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"

     />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btncancel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnLike"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"

     />
```

listview.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/list"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent">
 </ListView>
```

Comment: try to remove your `getItem()` and `getItemId()`..and run it..

Answer (score 0):

Try to change change it like,,

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
        }
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        name.setText(Name[position]);
        EditText editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setHint("write here");
        Button btn1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnok);
        name.setText("OK");
        Button btn2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
        name.setText("cancel");
        return convertView;
    }
```

and remove

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Name[arg0];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}
```

Comment: can't remove  getItem() and getItemId() functions because I have extended CustomAdapter class by BaseAdapter.

Answer (score -1):

Try it,

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
        }
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        name.setText(Name[position]);
        EditText editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setHint("write here");
        Button btn1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnok);
        name.setText("OK");
        Button btn2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
        name.setText("cancel");
        return convertView;
    }
```